# leaflet-velocity - cannot read property 'data' of null

Tags: python, json, leaflet, netcdf

I am working on the wind animation by using leaflet-velocity.js, which can be found in either npm or github (https://github.com/danwild/leaflet-velocity) from my own atmospheric model output (WRF).

To perform the wind animation, I wrote down my own python code to convert the model output from netCDF format to json format. The code is showing below

```
import os, sys, json, numpy as np
from glob import glob
from netCDF4 import Dataset, num2date, date2num

#- header templete
header = {  
    'parameterUnit': 'm.s-1',
    'parameterNumber': 2,
    'dx': 1.0,
    'dy': 1.0,
    'parameterNumberName': 'eastward_wind',
    'la1': 90.0,
    'la2': -90.0,
    'parameterCategory': 2,
    'lo1': 0.0,
    'nx': 360,
    'ny': 181,
    'refTime': '2016-04-30T06:00:00.000Z',
    'lo2': 359.0,
    }

lists = glob('TXGLO.surf_wind4json.nc')
ntimes= 8
for fid in lists[:1]:
    nc = Dataset(fid)
    tm = nc.variables['Times'][:]
    dim1, dim2 = nc.variables['XLAT'][0].shape
    nPoints = dim1*dim2
    lat= np.flipud(nc.variables['XLAT'][0]).flatten().tolist()
    lon= np.flipud(nc.variables['XLONG'][0]+360.).flatten().tolist()
    header['nx'] = dim1
    header['ny'] = dim2
    header['la1']= lat[0]
    header['la2']= lat[-1]
    header['lo1']= lon[0]
    header['lo2']= lon[-1]
    numPoints = nPoints
    for num, tim in enumerate(tm[:1]):
        refTime = ''.join(tim).replace('_',' ')
        print(' Processing file : '+fid+' , time : '+str(num)+' '+refTime)
        header['refTime'] = refTime
        with open('cresm_atmos_surf.json','w') as outfile:  
            outfile.write('[')
            #-  U10
            header['parameterNumberName'] = 'eastward_wind'
            u10 = np.flipud(nc.variables['U10'][num]).flatten().tolist()
            json.dump({'data':u10,'header':header}, outfile)
            outfile.write(',')
            #- V10
            header['parameterNumberName'] = 'northward_wind'
            v10 = np.flipud(nc.variables['V10'][num]).flatten().tolist()
            json.dump({'data':v10,'header':header}, outfile)
            outfile.write(']')
```

The results of json output looks like similar with the demo json file, such as wind-gbr.json (https://github.com/danwild/leaflet-velocity/blob/master/demo/wind-gbr.json)

Once I completed the converter, I refreshed my web page and found out there is an error on reading my json file.

[image]

[image]

Could someone please help me to figure out what is the error?

Thank You,

my netcdf file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/tmyrrinraetvcxs/TXGLO.surf_wind4json.nc?dl=0

my json file : 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/huiffld05zmldrs/cresm_atmos_surf.json?dl=0

the demo json file :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/17pr3vdkl1v3bq7/wind_gbr.json?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you step down the error call stack, you will inspect [`createBuilder`](https://github.com/danwild/leaflet-velocity/blob/v1.2.1/src/js/windy.js#L79-L98) function which shows you how it extracts `uComp` and `vComp` from your provided JSON data.

You will see that it uses your records header `parameterCategory` and `parameterNumber` fields to determine whether the record data should be assigned to `uComp` or `vComp`:

```js
switch (record.header.parameterCategory + "," + record.header.parameterNumber) {
  case "1,2":
  case "2,2":
    uComp = record;
    break;
  case "1,3":
  case "2,3":
    vComp = record;
    break;
  default:
    scalar = record;
}
```

It looks like your data has 2 records with exactly the same values for these 2 fields:

```
"parameterNumber": 2,
"parameterCategory": 2
```

Therefore you do not seem to provide `vComp` type record.

By forcing one of your records with `"parameterNumber": 3`, leaflet-velocity script no longer throws an error and displays something on the map, although it might not be the appropriate display.

Comment: Thanks ghybs, this does rescue me from several days bug search game.