# Formatting json for leaflet wind map

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, data-conversion, netcdf

I'm trying to convert netCDF data to json for use in [leaflet-velocity](https://github.com/danwild/leaflet-velocity), which used the same format as the output of [grib2json](https://github.com/cambecc/grib2json) used by cambecc in [earth](https://github.com/cambecc/earth). Here's another example of sample json data given by danwild in [wind-global.json](https://github.com/danwild/leaflet-velocity/blob/master/demo/wind-global.json)

Using [netCDF4](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/) I've managed to extract arrays of lat/ lot wind data from my netCDF.

I was wondering how the "data" part of the json file (example below) is structured? It seems to be a long array of values (e.g. for 'eastward wind' in the example), but I don't understand how they get mapped to lat/ lon coords later on?

Is there something in the json header which tells Leaflet how to structure the output, or must there be another function in leaflet-velocity.js doing the work?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46699194/leaflet-velocity-cannot-read-property-data-of-null) had some clues, but I've been at a loss for some time now trying to adapt it for my own netCDF file.

```
[
{
    "header": {
    "parameterUnit": "m.s-1",
    "parameterNumber": 2,
    "dx": 1.0,
    "dy": 1.0,
    "parameterNumberName": "eastward_wind",
    "la1": -7.5,
    "la2": -28.5,
    "parameterCategory": 2,
    "lo2": 156.0,
    "nx": 14,
    "ny": 22,
    "refTime": "2017-02-01 23:00:00",
    "lo1": 143.0
  },
    "data":[
        -2.12,
        -2.27,
        -2.41,
        ...
    ]
}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

This may help. [NCO-JSON](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#jsn) produces a different JSON dialect than `grib2json`, yet works directly and completely for all netCDF files, and, by default, includes brackets indicating array dimensional boundaries. You might find it easier for your purposes...

```
zender@aerosol:~$ ncks -C -v three_dmn_rec_var --jsn ~/nco/data/in.nc
{
  "dimensions": {
    "lat": 2,
    "lon": 4,
    "time": 10
  },
  "variables": {
    "three_dmn_rec_var": {
      "shape": ["time", "lat", "lon"],
      "type": "float",
      "attributes": {
        "long_name": "three dimensional record variable",
        "units": "watt meter-2",
        "_FillValue": -99.0
      },
      "data": [[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0]], [[9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0], [13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0]], [[17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0], [21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0]], [[25.0, 26.0, 27.0, 28.0], [29.0, 30.0, 31.0, 32.0]], [[33.0, 34.0, 35.0, 36.0], [37.0, 38.0, 39.0, 40.0]], [[41.0, 42.0, 43.0, 44.0], [45.0, 46.0, 47.0, 48.0]], [[49.0, 50.0, 51.0, 52.0], [53.0, 54.0, 55.0, 56.0]], [[57.0, 58.0, 59.0, 60.0], [61.0, 62.0, 63.0, 64.0]], [[65.0, 66.0, 67.0, 68.0], [69.0, 70.0, 71.0, 72.0]], [[73.0, 74.0, 75.0, 76.0], [77.0, 78.0, 79.0, 80.0]]]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Charlie.

In the end I worked out how the "data" part of the original JSON was structured. It cycles through from west to east then north to south, filling in data points based on a starting point (la1, lo1) and step (dx, dy) defined in the "header".

I think the best solution may have been to use your NCO-JSON tool to do netCDF to JSON and to reformat the JSON to fit the input needed for wind-global.json. Will do this in future projects.

Cheers

Comment: @F.Lumley This is a bit late, but could you explain how you worked out how the "data" part works? I have been searching for an answer/documentation high and low, but to no avail. If you could shine a light on the dx/dy, nx/ny etc. that would be great!

Comment: hey @Agent.Logic_ apologies it's been a while since I worked on this! I'm not 100% sure I fully got to the bottom of it but the finsihed project is here: https://github.com/smlum/netcdf-vis I think the python script at app/data/netcdf2leaflet.py was where I dealt with dx/dy etc. I'll try and get round to revisiting at some point!

Comment: Thanks a lot @F.Lumley! That should probably offer me some clues, will dig in to it and see what I can make of it. Cheers!

Comment: great let us know if you get to the bottom of it!